# WordPress / WooCommerce google social login with linking to existing user

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress woocommerce website which has normal login system, but now I want to include social login for new users as well as for old users who has already entered their google email Id while registering on old login system.

When an old user with same email id (old login system) log's in to the website I wanna show his orders which he has done using old login system and social login system too.

Comment: This is not a  WooCommerce specific issue, but WordPress. Any plugin for WordPress for social login that links user email from social login to existing user can be helpful for this.

Comment: @niklaz Thanks for the reply, is there any article you wanna suggest. I have been stuck for 3 days now.

Comment: I would suggest these 2:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/  and https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/ first one has good intro tutorial how to setup

Comment: @niklaz thanks for your help, I used super socializer plugin which solved my problem.